# Vim EasyMotion search matches

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

[Vim EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) has search character using:

```
<Leader>fc
```

which highlights all occurrences of character from which i can choose.

Is there an equivalent motion for search matches like

```
<Leader>fadd
```

which hightlights all occurrences of phrase "add" from which i can choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<leader>f{char}` brings you to character, not a search pattern. (now default `<leader><leader>f` )

The way I am using this plugin is, I am watching the position (char or word) I want to go to, type `<leader><leader>f or w...`, type the highlighted letter to move my cursor to the right position. So I don't have a requirement of going to a certain pattern using easymotion.

however what you want is possible. you could search `add` first, by `/` or `?`, then type `<leader><leader>n` or `<leader><leader>N` all `add`s are with a prefix, which you could choose.

(if your easymotion mapping is with single `<leader>`, change the double leaders to single)

read 
`:h easymotion`

> 2.1  Default mappings

for detail